# PHP Script for Christmas calendar

Tags: php, date, timezone

I'm creating a PHP script for a Christmas calendar which is supposed to only load the respective content (some text and images) based on the current (December) date.

For example, on the 1st December (based on the PHP script) only the specified content should be shown. On the 2nd December, the specific content for that day/date should be shown.

My problem now is to ensure that in Germany we, obviously, have a different time zone than in (for me important) Vancouver, Canada.

How can I get the script working with the right request/checks on loading for the timezone/date that in these two particular timezones the content is visible at all times (while it is for instance the 1st of December in one of these timezones)??

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is based on the assumption that you use a webpage to show the user timezone.*

First note that you can not get the user timezone in PHP. But what you can do is tell the server what the user date is via JavaScript.

You can do something like this:

```
var currentdate = new Date();
if(currentdate.getMonth() === 11){ // note that January = 0, Feb = 1 etc. So December = 11
    $.get( "//christmasServer.com/timezone.php?user_day=" + currentdate.getDate(), function( data ) { // send to server, getDate() will show the day, December 14 will just show 14
      $('.Christmas').html( data ); // do something with the data, for example replace the div .Christmas
    });
} else {
    // It's not even december in your timezone :-o
}
```

In `timezone.php` you can now determine what the day is.

**As addition:**
You can set the timezone in the `$_SESSION` so that you only have to set it once.

*timezone.php*:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_timezone'])){ // if timezone isn't set
    session_start(); // start session
    $_SESSION['user_timezone'] = $_GET['user_day'];
}

if($_SESSION['user_timezone']===1){ // if it's the first of December
    echo 'I\'m shown December first';
} else if($_SESSION['user_timezone']===2){ // if it's the second of December
    echo 'I\'m shown December second';
}

// etc...
```

You can now always use `$_SESSION['user_timezone']` to get the users' timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 
Now I'm stuck at the problem of using an array storing some values inside, creating a function in the timezone.php to determine the day (so 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.) and based on that outcome the respective .Christmas class (using your example) should be filled with the value from the found day/value combination from the array... You know what I mean? :/

Comment: Hi @maximizeIT, check the update.
Now note that on the second of December, the `data` variable in JS will contain: `I'm shown December second`. So, if you have a `div` that has the class `Christmas` it's inner value will be replaced with `I'm shown December second`

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I don't know what am I doing wrong...it doesn't work at all for me...

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

In my  of index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentdate = new Date();

if(currentdate.getMonth() === 10){ // for testing with november (=10)
    $.get( "/timezone.php?user_day=" + currentdate.getDate(), function( data ) { // correct for localhost testing version, so no domain yet?!
      $('.Christmas').html( data ); // do something with the data, for example replace the div .Christmas
    });
} else {
    // It's not even december in your timezone :-o
}
</script>
```

Later in the index.php:

...

```
<div class="Christmas">
</div>
```

...

In my timezone.php (in same folder):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_timezone'])){ // if timezone isn't set
session_start(); // start session
$_SESSION['user_timezone'] = $_GET['user_day'];}
if($_SESSION['user_timezone']===1){ // if it's the first of December
echo 'Im shown December first';} else if($_SESSION['user_timezone']===2){ // if it's the second of December
echo 'Im shown December second';}
```